# Using Z-score with non-standard Gaussian probability density function

Tags: statistics, gaussian

I have a Gaussian probability density function

$$\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2 \pi}} exp[-\frac{(x-5)^2}{32}]$$

clearly $\mu = 5$ and $\sigma=4$

I would like to find $p(x\le n) = 0.0158$. I see in the standard z-score table that $p(x\le -2.149) \approx 0.0158$. However this is for a Gaussian with $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 1$.

What would I do to this result in order to find the answer to the non-standard Gaussian?

Thank you for your time

Edit: Fixed z-score

Comment: If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $P(X\leq n)=P(Z\leq \frac{n-\mu}{\sigma})$ for $Z$ standard normal

Comment: So, to answer the question, I am looking for a d such that $\frac{d-\mu}{\sigma}$ = 0.2? I.e. $d=5.8$?

Comment: But I am confused how you found $P(Z\leq 0.2)=0.0158$ for $Z$ standard normal. Think about it: the probability that $Z$ is less than $0.2$ is more than than the probability that $Z$ is less than $0$, which is $0.5$.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio I was just looking at a z-score table in a textbook. It says has "absolute value less than criteria" so perhaps this affects this. What you say makes sense, I'm not sure what they mean by absolute value less than criteria

Comment: The updated calculation, i.e. $P(Z\leq -1.405)=0.0158$, is still off though (think about the 68 95 99.7 rule). I am getting [$P(Z\leq -2.149)=0.0158$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=invnorm%28.0158%29)

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thanks, I mistakenly was taking ~ half the value ($0.08$) due to some poorly formatted notes.